# Do I have to worry about asynchronous processing when I am using SFMC-fuel SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, c#

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and install SFMC.FuelSDK using Nuget. My program use SDK's methods to insert data in data extension, and send triggered email.

I read through an API document showing about asynchronous processing which can help in case of the ET's server is down. Does the SDK take care of the case or I have to implement asynchronous processing? If so, can someone give me an example about how to implement it?

Here is my code doing insert data to data extension:

```
ETDataExtensionRow deRowGet = new ETDataExtensionRow();
deRowGet.AuthStub = myclient;
deRowGet.DataExtensionName = DE;
deRowGet.Props = new string[] {"id"};
deRowGet.SearchFilter = new SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "email", 
SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals, Value = new string[] { email } };
GetReturn grRow = deRowGet.Get();
```

What does this line mean or used for?

```
deRowGet.Props = new string[] {"id"};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check our latest Unit Test code for DataExtension here:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/master/FuelSDK-Test/ETDataExtensionRowTest.cs

Comment: I read through the document, but it doesn't show any asynchronous processing. Do you suggest me to use Assert instead?